# Confused by Excel formula

Tags: excel

I am an university final year student and I'm working on my research project.

I have to perform simulation by using MS Excel and there's a problem which keep confusing me during this process.

When, I'm doing the simulation, I type the following formula

> =IF(B14>16000,"0",IF(B14<200,"1","0"))

what I'm trying to do is " IF B14 (water tank) is smaller than 16000, the pump will turn on, marked as "1", else it will be turned off, marked as "0".

I wanna make the tank be filled up when there's not enough of water inside it. 
However, the formula turns out stop the pump once the water tank storage is more than 200.

What I want to achieve, is refill the water tank to almost its full capacity, not stopping it once the capacity is just above 200.

Is there any formula pattern i could be adopted in tis situation? 
Thanks you so much,

Comment: Your text implies this formula: `=IF(B14<16000, "1", "0")`

Comment: what do you mean by "not enough water inside" is this not less than 16000?

Comment: Are you certain of your logic?  In your *trying to do*, there is no mention of `200`, so you shouldn't need that factor in the equation at all.  I suspect what you want would be something like: `If B14 falls to less than 200, turn pump on until it gets up to 16000, then turn it off`.  If that is the case, you need another cell to tell whether the pump is running or not. (or enable circular references to do it in a single cell)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yes i did include a cell telling the pump is on or off, in order to calculate the water flow into and out of the water tank, what you said is exactly what i am trying to do, but my result become
> once the tank capacity gets up to more than 200 the pump will turn off

Comment: @dan6657 there's no exact guideline on designing the water supply system that I'm researching so the professor asked me to perform this simulation. 

in this case " not enough water inside " is only defined by myself, so set the minimum to be 200, when the water volume is smaller than 200L, the pump will turn on and fill up the tank till 16000L

Comment: It seems that this is a dynamical module, therefore knowing only the current state is not enough. Show us more details, such as how much "water" will be pumped each time interval, or something like how is the water to be consumed. Are these action done in one cell? Or is there an array of cells listing all states within each time interval?

Comment: @newacc2240 i got a column, named tank 1, a column named pump (1 or 0, shows the pump whether it is on or off, a column shows the flow rate into the tank, says its 10.6 L/s, a columns shows the flow rate out of the tank (8.15L/s)

so the tank initially contain 16200L of water, and the simulation goes on, the  water volume is decrease with the rate 8.15L/s, i set the interval to be 10s, so each row will deduct 8.15*10 L, and once the water volume reach below 200L, the pump will turn on and pump 10.6L/s into the tank to refill.

Comment: So you are recording all the states when t=10s, 20s, 30s,.......right?

Comment: @newacc2240 exactly

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
=IF(B14>16000,0,IF(B14<200,0,1))
```

So, if the tank is full then "off",
    if the tank is not full and less than 200 then off,
      otherwise the pump is on.

Comment: thanks Mike, your method can keep the tank to be filled up in certain level, however the pump will be turned on and off so frequently, is there any possible formula to make the pump be turned on when the water volume inside the water dropped down to 200L and when the turn off after filled up the tank to 16000L?

thanks so much for helping me, sorry for my limited english haha

Comment: Your question states yhat if the level is below 200 then the pump should be off, so that is what I gave you. If you have your logic incorrect then change the staus around...

Comment: omg sorry for the typo haha i was in a rush when i typed the question, so the pump will start once the level is below 200 and stop once the level reach 16000 again, sorry my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response to my comment:

If you have a cell (named `Status`) that returns `1` or `0` depending on if the pump is currently `on` or `off`, then you can use:

```
=IF(B14<200,1,IF(B14>16000,0,Status))
```

If you do not have such a cell, you can do this in a single cell by enabling `iterative calculations`  (See Tools/Options/Formulas) and using this formula:

```
C14:  =IF(OR(B14<200,AND(B14<16000,C14=1)),1,0)
^^^                                ^^^
```

Note the cell reference in the formula being the same as the cell in which the formula exists.

Comment: got it , thanks so much Ron, i will try to modify my worksheet. thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

My chart looks like this:

```
    B       C       D       E       F
1   Tank 1  Pump    In      Out     TimeInterval
2   16200   0       10.6    8.15    10
3   16118.5 0       10.6    8.15    10
4   16037   0       10.6    8.15    10
5   15955.5 0       10.6    8.15    10
```

Row 2 is the initial state, input the values manually. Formulas I'm using are:

```
B3=B2-E2*F2+D2*F2*C2
C3=IF(B2<200,1,IF(AND(B2<16000,C2=1),1,0)
```